# Is there any scala library that treat tuples as monads

Tags: scala, tuples, monads

Is there any scala library that enriches basic scala tuples with monad syntax. Something similar to the Writer monad but adjusted for usage with tuples.

What I look for:

```
val pair = (2, "as")
pair >>= (a => point(a+1))
```

should equal to `(3, "as")`. As well as

```
for (p <- pair) yield (p+1)
```

Comment: Can you post some example code that you expect to work? I don't know what exactly you are asking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) provides monad instances for tuples (up to `Tuple8`):

```
import scalaz.std.anyVal._, scalaz.std.tuple._, scalaz.syntax.monad._

scala> type IntTuple[A] = (Int, A)
defined type alias IntTuple

scala> pair >>= (a => (a+1).point[IntTuple])
res0: (Int, String) = (2,as1)

scala> for (p <- pair) yield (p + 1)
res1: (Int, String) = (2,as1)
```

(Note that the type alias isn't necessary—it just makes using `point` a little easier.)

Comment: I forgot about this completely!